# Android Table Layout: Button expands over full row

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am using a table layout in my `android` application.

I have "Button EditText Button" that shall fill a row. The two buttons shall only take what they need to display their respective button text, anything else should be taken by EditText.

For reasons I don't manage to google, the first button takes the full line width. Anyone knows why?

My .xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/primaryControls"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/radicalClearButton"
            android:text="@string/radicalClearButton" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/radical"
            android:hint="@string/radical_input" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/radicalGoButton"
            android:text="@string/radicalGoButton" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/separatorRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/radicalView_separator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#000000" />
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/primaryControls"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/radicalClearButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/radicalClearButton" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/radical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/radical_input" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/radicalGoButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/radicalGoButton" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/separatorRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/radicalView_separator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#000000" />
</TableRow>
```